# How do I remove a newline that is the last char in an array?

Tags: c

So, I am trying to remove a newline that is the last char in an array. The issue is, that in earlier lines I need the newline break, so when I create the array, I leave it in there, so it looks like this:

```
fgets(input, 100, stdin);

char *array[10];
int i = 0;

array[i] = strtok(input, " ");

while(array[i] != NULL)
    array[++i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

but later on, when I run

```
execvp("echo", array);
```

It has an extra line break that I can't get rid of, like this (what it would look like from console):

```
(input) echo "hello"
(output) hello
(output)
*Continues code from here*
```

I am just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I could remove the linebreak so, that when I run the `execvp`, there would not be an extra line?

Comment: By using the delimiter set `" \r\n"` for `strtok`.

Comment: @bobChicken It is enough to use the delimiter " \n" in calls of strtok.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code snippet I use to remove the newline (before strtok).

```
fgets(in_line, LINE_LENGTH, stdin);
if ((strlen(in_line) > 0) && (in_line[strlen(in_line) -1] == '\n') )
    in_line[strlen(in_line)-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: [`buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)  Note, though, that will terminate the string on any newline.

Comment: J27avier, `strlen(in_line) > 0` better coded as `in_line[0] != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

> To remove a newline that is the last char in an array

```
input[100-1] = 0;
```

> To remove a newline at the end of a *string* fill by `fgets()`

```
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;
```